# React form update state based on props for v16.13

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I try to learn it from the recent official documentation where 'componentWillReceiveProps' no longer in lifecycle.

I have a Children component for NEW Product to post :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class NewProduct extends Component {

state = {   
    title : "",
    price : 0   
}

  handleChange =(e)=>{
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }); 
  }

  handleSubmit =()=>{

    let formData = {
      title : this.state.title,
      price : this.state.price  
    }
    console.log(formData)
    // axios here with formData
  }


  render() {   
    return (
       <div>       
           <input type="text"  name="title" value={this.state.title}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
           <input type="text"  name="price" value={this.state.price}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
           <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>      
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This works OK for creating product on database.

And For EDIT Product, the Parent component load data from database using axios and pass it as props to EditProduct Children. `<EditProduct productData={this.state.productData} />`

Edit form :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class EditProduct extends Component {

state = {   
    title : "",
    price : 0   
}

  handleChange =(e)=>{
    // how to handle change........???
  }

  handleSubmit =()=>{

    let formData = {
      title : this.state.title,
      price : this.state.price  
    }
    console.log(formData)
    // axios here with formData
  }


  render() { 

  const data = this.props.productData;

    return (
       <div>       
           <input type="text"  name="title" value={data.title || ""}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
           <input type="text"  name="price" value={data.price || ""}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
           />
           <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>      
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My problem is I can not change the state by using handleChange since the value on each inputs no more refer to state.

I have tried to solve this problem by using componentWillReceiveProps and change the states by setState. But this method is no more mentioned inside lifecycle, so I need other solution.

Other solution I have tried was using context API where parent store data to state and my EditProduct component consume and modify that states.

My question is : What is the best valid ways to replace componentWillReceiveProps?

Note : Please do not suggest Redux.

Comment: maybe it helps [https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Comment: @aseferorov Based on Docs ,this method exists for rare use cases. But my case is not rare. There must be a  'not rare' solution.